# How can I get a Kerberos ticket with Delphi?

Tags: web-services, delphi, active-directory, kerberos

Are there examples which show how Delphi invokes the Active Directory Kerberos server to request a ticket granting ticket / normal ticket?

Background: the ticket is required for authentification to a web service which exchanges confidential information.

Edit: a short source code example would be very helpful. I have found the [JEDI Windows Security Code Library](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/security-library/) which is very impressing. I am not sure if it contains support for Kerberos.

Comment: see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15455

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380496(VS.85).aspx) you should be able to get one with the [InitializeSecurityContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375507(VS.85).aspx) windows API call.

Comment: Thank you for the link - however to use it in Delphi it looks like many API record structures have to be created and filled first. I have started a bounty, maybe somebody can share some code.

Comment: Most Win32 API headers have been converted under the JEDI project (http://jedi-apilib.sourceforge.net/), and if it's not there I usually use google's codesearch (http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=initializesecuritycontext+lang:pascal) to find hat I need.

Comment: There is some old code here http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/16213 that demonstrates how to call InitializeSecurityContext with NTLM credentials. It may be a decent start for anyone attempting to get a Kerberos ticket.

Answer (score 1):

First read [Kerberizing Applications Using Security Support Provider Interface](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=20989) to get the general idea. `InitializeSecurityContext` is described as following:

> Initiates a security context by
>   generating a security token that must
>   be passed to the server. The
>   application that uses this function is
>   called an SSPI client.

On msdn, the list of SSPI functions can be found in [Authentication Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374731%28VS.85%29.aspx).

For actual example code, see Win32 samples's [SSPI page](http://win32.mvps.org/security/sspi.html). You probably find  [client.cpp](http://win32.mvps.org/security/client.cpp) to be useful. Another similar example is [GssClient.c](http://web.mit.edu/jaltman/Public/kfw/gss/GssClient.c). Both code are running it in a loop because the conversation keeps going if `SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED` is returned.