# Are there HTTP client libraries for Delphi which suport NTLMSSP authentication?

Tags: delphi, http, authentication, indy, ntlm

We recently started using a Squid HTTP proxy server which provides **squid-2.5-ntlmssp** authentification.

Does somebody know if [NTLMSSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLMSSP) is supported by one of the popular HTTP client libraries for Delphi (Indy, Synapse, ICS, nsoftware ...)?

Update: I just read in Wikipedia that

> The Windows Service offering the acceptor side of NTLMSSP has been
>   removed from Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 in favor of the
>   newer Kerberos authentication protocol.

So I guess that this auth method will be replaced by Kerberos soon - anyway I'll leave this question - for 'historic studies', or companies which always are a little behind current rocket-science etc. ;)

Related question: [How can I get a Kerberos ticket with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052369/how-can-i-get-a-kerberos-ticket-with-delphi)

Comment: So should this question be closed as unanswerable? (How do you use something in delphi that is now removed from versions of windows later than XP?)

Comment: Did you check out the Jedi API wrappers? reference: http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid2A4442C72A6294A399C120AD41BD4AD6435F01E1.aspx

Comment: This question is answerable and for companies which still use NTLMSSP an answer could be very helpful because it removes the need for IP-based proxy authentication of all computers where apps without NTLMSSP support are running

Answer (score 1):

It seems [Wininet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385331%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) should support it when [enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384220%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the registry.
Indy includes a unit named `IdAuthenticationNTLM.pas` so it probably supports it, too.

Comment: the IdAuthenticationNTLM and IdAuthenticationSSPI auth handlers both just abort the communication with the proxy, giving no further error code