# Acquiring a Kerberos ticket with a Delphi application

Tags: delphi, kerberos

I am at a loss here. For some weeks now I tried to get a Kerberos ticket with my Delphi application.

I consulted:

- [How can I get a Kerberos ticket with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052369/how-can-i-get-a-kerberos-ticket-with-delphi) (I honestly don't see why the bounty was rewarded, btw)
- Every page around https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- Most importantly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee498143.aspx

The last page links to example code that I converted to Delphi - I think. On a form I dropped a TWSocket out of Overbytes Socket components and named it  mySocket. Rest is done in code. Problem is, that I seem to get the Kerberos TGT, but can't get the Ticket itself through the UDP connection. The Server just wont answer. I also feel there is something fundamentally wrong here, with the break of media during the communication with the server. How come I can use API to get the TGT but have to switch to UDP to get the ticket itself?

Maybe a good start to discuss this is to ignore the code first and tell me if the way I'm going is right or not. Here are my steps:

1. Call InitSecurityInterface to get the SecurityFunctionTable
2. Call QuerySecurityPackageInfo for the Kerberos Package to obtain max message size
3. Call AcquireCredentialsHandle for Kerberos package
4. Call InitializeSecurityContext with above received CredentialsHandle and the KerberosServer. Receiving some message, that may contain a KerbTicket a Kerb TGT or anything inbetween
5. Depending on the result of InitializeSecurityContext either use received KerbTicket or open UDP connection to KerbServer to send received buffer from step 4
6. Use answer message as parameter for new call of InitilizeSecurityContext
7. Repeat from Step 4 until result is SEC_E_OK

Have I understood correctly? If so, please consider reading my implementation to find my mistake. If not, please explain how it's really done.

Here is the code:

```
unit ukerber;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  IdSSPI, IdAuthenticationSSPI, Vcl.StdCtrls, OverbyteIcsWndControl,
  OverbyteIcsWSocket;

const
  krbServer: PAnsiChar = 'krbtgt/mydomain.int';

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    mySocket: TWSocket;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mySocketDataAvailable(Sender: TObject; ErrCode: Word);
    function InitPackage(var maxMessage: Cardinal): Boolean;
    function SendUDPMessage(outBuf: Pointer; outsize: Cardinal): Boolean;
    function GenClientContext(pIn: Pointer; InputSize: Cardinal; pOut: Pointer; Outputsize: PCardinal; var Done: Boolean): Boolean;
    procedure Cleanup;
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    secfunc: SecurityFunctionTableA;
    maxMessageSize: Cardinal;
    hCredential: SecHandle;
    hContext: CtxtHandle;
    pOutBuf, pInBuf: PByteArray;
    MessageReceived: Boolean;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

procedure Pause(Zeit: Longint);

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

// the main method from the C-example
// this starts the ticket acquisition
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sec_State: SECURITY_STATUS;
  pszTargetName: PSEC_CHAR;

  hNewContext: CtxtHandle;
  Output, Input: SecBufferDesc;
  outSecBuf, inSecBuf: SecBuffer;
  fContextAttr: ULONG;

  cbOut, cbIn: Cardinal;
  Done: Boolean;
  timeOut: Integer;
begin
  Done := False;
  if InitPackage(maxMessageSize) then
  begin
    try
      pOutBuf := nil;
      pInBuf := nil;

      GetMem(pOutBuf, maxMessageSize);
      GetMem(pInBuf, maxMessageSize);
      SecInvalidateHandle(hCredential);
      SecInvalidateHandle(hContext);

      if not GenClientContext(nil, 0, pOutBuf, @cbOut, Done) then
      begin
        Cleanup;
        Exit;
      end;

      // ------------
      // up to here everything seem to work just fine
      // ------------
      if not SendUDPMessage(pOutBuf, cbout) then
      begin
        Cleanup;
        Exit;
      end;
      timeOut := 0;

      while not Done and (timeOut <= 100) do
      begin
        repeat
          Pause(1000);
          Inc(timeOut);
        until MessageReceived or (timeOut >= 100);

        if MessageReceived then
        begin
          cbOut := maxMessageSize;
          if not GenClientContext(pInBuf, cbIn, pOutBuf, @cbout, Done) then
          begin
            Cleanup;
            Exit;
          end;
          if not SendUDPMessage(pOutBuf, cbout) then
          begin
            Cleanup;
            Exit;
          end;

        end;
      end;

      if Done then  // <<<----------Sadly... never done
      begin
        // Kerberos-ticket ---->>>>  pInBuf

      end
      else  // this happens every time
        ShowMessage('Authentification failed due to server timeout');
    finally
      Cleanup;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Cleanup;
begin
  secfunc.DeleteSecurityContext(@hcontext);
  secfunc.FreeCredentialsHandle(@hCredential);
  FreeMem(pInBuf);
  FreeMem(pOutBuf);
end;

function TForm2.GenClientContext(pIn: Pointer; InputSize: Cardinal;
  pOut: Pointer; Outputsize: PCardinal; var Done: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  sec_State: SECURITY_STATUS;
  LifeTime: TimeStamp;
  OutBuffDesc: SecBufferDesc;
  OutSecBuff: SecBuffer;
  InBuffDesc: SecBufferDesc;
  InSecBuff: SecBuffer;
  ContextAttributes: ULONG;
  NewContext: Boolean;
  KerberosServer: PAnsiChar;

  function SetSecHandle: PSecHandle;
  begin
    if NewContext then
      Result := nil
    else
      Result := @hContext;
  end;

  function SetInBuffer: PSecBufferDesc;
  begin
    if NewContext then
      Result := nil
    else
      Result := @InBuffDesc;
  end;

begin
  if not Assigned(pIn) then
  begin
    NewContext := True;
  // No user athentication needed, so we'll skip that part of the example
    sec_State := secfunc.AcquireCredentialsHandleA(
      nil,
      PAnsiChar('Kerberos'),
      SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND,
      nil,
      nil,
      nil,
      nil,
      @hCredential,
      @LifeTime
      );
    if not SEC_SUCCESS(sec_State) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('AqcuireCredentials failed, Error#: ' + IntToStr(sec_State));
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

    // Prepare buffers
    // Output
  OutBuffDesc.ulVersion := SECBUFFER_VERSION;
  OutBuffDesc.cBuffers := 1;
  OutBuffDesc.pBuffers := @OutSecBuff;

  OutSecBuff.cbBuffer := Outputsize^;
  OutSecBuff.BufferType := SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
  OutSecBuff.pvBuffer := pOut;

    //Input
  InBuffDesc.ulVersion := SECBUFFER_VERSION;
  InBuffDesc.cBuffers := 1;
  InBuffDesc.pBuffers := @InSecBuff;

  InSecBuff.cbBuffer := InputSize;
  InSecBuff.BufferType := SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
  InSecBuff.pvBuffer := pIn;

//  KerberosServer := krbServer;  // Tried both krbtgt and following...no change
  KerberosServer := PAnsiChar('RestrictedKrbHost/FM-DC01.mydomain.int');

  sec_State := secfunc.InitializeSecurityContextA(
    @hCredential,
    SetSecHandle,
    KerberosServer,                                                              
    ISC_REQ_DELEGATE + ISC_REQ_MUTUAL_AUTH,
    0,
    SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP,
    SetInBuffer,
    0,
    @hContext,
    @OutBuffDesc,
    @contextAttributes,
    @Lifetime
    );

  if not SEC_SUCCESS(sec_State) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('init context failed, Error #: ' + IntToStr(sec_State));
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  if (sec_State = SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED) or
    (sec_State = SEC_I_COMPLETE_AND_CONTINUE) then
  begin
    sec_State := secfunc.CompleteAuthToken(@hContext, @OutBuffDesc);
    if not SEC_SUCCESS(sec_State) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('complete failed, Error #: ' + IntToStr(sec_State));
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Outputsize^ := OutSecBuff.cbBuffer;

  // First call of this method results in sec_state = SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED 
  // which should be OK, but then I have to switch to UDP communication
  // and that seems to be buggy.

  Done := not ((sec_State = SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED) or (sec_State = SEC_I_COMPLETE_AND_CONTINUE));
  Result := True;
end;

function TForm2.InitPackage(var maxMessage: Cardinal): Boolean;
var
  sec_State: SECURITY_STATUS;
  pPkgInfo: PSecPkgInfoA;
  InitSecurityInterfaceA: function: PSecurityFunctionTableA; stdcall;
begin
  Result := False;
  MessageReceived := False;
  try
    InitSecurityInterfaceA := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('secur32.dll'), 'InitSecurityInterfaceA');
    if Assigned(InitSecurityInterfaceA) then
      secfunc := InitSecurityInterfaceA^;

    sec_State := secfunc.QuerySecurityPackageInfoA(
      PAnsiChar('Kerberos'),
      @pPkgInfo
      );

    if sec_state = SEC_E_OK then
    begin
      maxMessage := pPkgInfo^.cbMaxToken;
      Result := True;
    end;
  finally
    secfunc.FreeContextBuffer(pPkgInfo);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.mySocketDataAvailable(Sender: TObject; ErrCode: Word);
var
  inBuf: array of Byte;
  BufLen: Integer;
  Length: Integer;
  sentSize: Cardinal;
begin
  MessageReceived := False;
  // Data should pour in here. Hopefully the Kerberos-ticket
  // First DWORD is message size, rest is the message itself
  Length := mySocket.Receive(@sentsize, SizeOf(DWORD));
  if Length <= 0 then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;
  // The rest
  SetLength(inBuf, SizeOf(sentSize));
  Length := mySocket.Receive(@inBuf, SizeOf(inBuf));
  if Length >= 0 then
  begin
    pInBuf := @inBuf;
    MessageReceived := True;
  end;
end;

function TForm2.SendUDPMessage(outBuf: Pointer; outsize: Cardinal): Boolean;
begin
  mySocket.Proto := 'udp';
  mySocket.Addr := 'FM-DC01.mydomain.int';
  mySocket.Port := '88';
  mySocket.Connect;
  // send size of message first, then message itself
  Result := (mySocket.Send(PByte(@outsize), SizeOf(outsize)) > -1);
  if Result then
    if mySocket.State = wsConnected then
      Result := (mySocket.Send(outBuf, outsize) > -1);
end;

// small method to wait for action, should not be part of the problem
procedure Pause(Zeit: Longint);
var
  Tick: DWORD;
  Event: THandle;
begin
  Event := CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);
  try
    Tick := GetTickCount + DWORD(Zeit);
    while (Zeit > 0) and
      (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, Event, False, Zeit, QS_ALLINPUT) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT) do
    begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      Zeit := Tick - GetTickCount;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(Event);
  end;
end;    

end.
```

Comment: You have a lot of code there - can you expand the question to document it and explain which bits do and do not function, or give the expected response, please?

Comment: Added some more coments. Starting point is the Button1click method. Basically I just translated the C-example to Delphi, keeping most of the method and variable names.

Comment: And added some more info. Mainly how I understand the algorithm of acquiring a ticket in "seven easy steps" so that reading the code may be unnecessary.

Comment: May be reading source of mORMot can help? Class TSQLRestServerAuthenticationSSPI

Comment: @AlexEgorov: Hummm, the seem to use some HTML-Get in the non API part of the ticket acquisition. I'm pretty sure hoewever that my PDC wont answer those. But I must be on the right track, for the rest looks pretty much like what I did. Still can't get over the fact, that this can't be done in 100% API-calls. Weird to say the least.

Comment: HTML part used for authentication from web browser in mORMot

Comment: Did You have any solution finally?

Comment: Did You have seen https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/180548/how-to-validate-user-credentials-on-microsoft-operating-systems ? Did it helps somehow?

Comment: @Nashev I solved this by writing a small .net app, that took care of this in a jiffy. But I have since changed my employer and don't have to worry about this nonsense any longer.